# if condition not working properly with && operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

it also shows the link for order where received_by_admin is True.

```
if order.payment_status == 'Paid' && order.received_by_admin != 'true'
   link_to "Payment Received", "orders/#{order.id}/?payment_status=Paid", class: "member_link", method: :put
end
```

Comment: If received_by_admin is a method which is returning a boolean value than you should write it like this:
if (order.payment_status == 'Paid' && order.received_by_admin == false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably because `received_by_admin` is a boolean? So

```
order.payment_status == 'Paid' && order.received_by_admin != true
```

or simpler

```
order.payment_status == 'Paid' && !order.received_by_admin
```

the point here is that `true != 'true'`